# Best approach to get position for navigation app in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-location, google-play-services

I'm thinking what's the best approach to be used in a navigation app in Android, I mean, I know I can use AsyncTask to get location on the background and then continuously change the UI, but I don't want to use it because I might want to show some other activity on top of the map for something (but I want the map to continue to get updates with locations (if I use AsyncTask, once I move out of that activity it will be paused).

IntentService on the background and get a handler to the UI in the Application class so then onLocationChanged use the handler to change the UI? Something better?
Same with sensors..OnSensorChanged, change the UI to show the values...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the new Location APIs in Google Play Services:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html. You can use this API to get regular updates in the form of Location objects. The updates arrive asynchronously, so you can respond to them as you want, but you don't have to go off the UI thread.

There's a training class for this with sample apps.